# Vue JS - Nav Class - hide nav option dependent on certain value

Tags: vue.js, menu, navigation

I have a number of menu items icons and dependent on an a variable wish to hide an option..

The code is:

```
<template>
  <main class="shell">
    <aside class="shell-nav">
      <nav class="nav-list">
        <ul>
          <li><router-link  to="xyz"><jam-grid/><span>xyz</span></router-link></li>
        </ul>
```

However, I'd like to add an extra route only if an admin condition is met...

```
<template>
  <main class="shell">
    <aside class="shell-nav">
      <nav class="nav-list">
        <ul>
          <li><router-link  to="xyz"><jam-grid/><span>xyz</span></router-link></li>

          <div v-if="isAdmin">
          <ul>
            <li><router-link to="settings"><jam-tools /><span>Settings</span></router-link></li>
          </ul>

        </ul>
      ...
```

How can I do this?

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

My Nav class is below:

```
<template>
  <main class="shell">
    <aside class="shell-nav" :class="sidebarOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'">
      <div class="nav-trigger" @click="openSidebar()">
        <jam-menu v-if="!sidebarOpen" />
        <jam-arrow-left v-if="sidebarOpen" />
      </div>
      <nav class="nav-list">
        <ul>
          <li><router-link  to="xyz"><jam-grid/><span>xyz</span></router-link></li>         
          <li v-if="isAdminUser"><router-link to="settings"><jam-tools /><span>Settings</span></router-link></li>                                
        </ul>                             
      </nav>
      <button class="nav-help"><jam-help /></button>
    </aside>
    <div class="shell-container">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      sidebarOpen: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    'this.$administrator': {
      handler: function (val) {
        console.log ("$administrator has changed: ", this.$administrator);
        vm.$forceUpdate();
      },
      deep: true,
    },   
    openSidebar: {
      handler: function (val) {
        console.log ("opensidebar changed: ", this.openSidebar);
        vm.$forceUpdate();
      },
      deep: true,
    },   
  },
  methods: {
    openSidebar() {
      console.log ("openSideBar");
      this.sidebarOpen = !this.sidebarOpen;
    },
    isAdmin()
    {
      var value = false;
      console.log ("isAdmin = ", value);
      if (this.$administrator > 0)
      {
          value = true;
      }
      value = false;
      return value;
    }
  },
  computed:
  {
     isAdminUser()
     {
      console.log ("isAdminUser: ", this.$administrator);
      this.$administrator;
     }
  },
 
};
</script>
```

I want to be able to do the following:

1. If the this.$administrator value changes, update the nav-list straight away so the setting entry is shown if admin=true and not if admin=false

Comment: You can just put your `v-if` directly on the `<li>` you want to conditionally render

Comment: where is the closing tag for `<div v-if="isAdmin">`?  If it's after the `</ul>` then you're already done.  It seems a bit too simple... If you're asking how to create `isAdmin`, you need to provide more information since "what is an Admin" depends on your app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help - i haven' t got it working yet, I've got a global variable called this.$administrator, which works - it's going to be a boolean to show if admin or not. Then the isAdmin just returns this value to show/hide the option. The problem I have now is I've changed the <li> to <li v-if="isAdmin" but this function is never called

Comment: is there a way I can refresh the aside menu if the global this.$administrator value changes, i've tried putting a watch on this, but it doesn't work.